# Можно ли создать кнопку на сайте для добавления ярлыка (ссылки на сайт) на главный экран смартфона Android/iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, apple, мобильная-разработка

Такой функционал есть например в мобильном браузере Chrome: Настройки -> Добавить на главный экран. Можно ли создать такую кнопку на сайте?

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-give-your-website-an-ios-home-screen-icon--webdesign-10067

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Это же про иконки!